# pl-sql equivalent for t-sql "UPDATE FROM" clause on temp tables

Tags: t-sql, plsql, sql-server-2014, oracle12c

In SQL Server stored procedure I have this code:

```
UPDATE #tbinforesult
SET prifix = ''
FROM #tbmax t
    INNER JOIN #tbinforesult i 
        ON i.prifix = t.prifix
            AND i.PropertyID = t.PropertyID
            AND i.GroupID = t.GroupID
            AND i.NID <> t.id
```

What is the equivalent in pl-sql with pl-sql collections not global temporary table?

Answer (score 1):

TSQL :

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table Table_A
INNER JOIN
    Other_Table Table_B
ON
    Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

PLSQL:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET (name, desc) = (SELECT t2.name, t2.desc
                         FROM table2 t2
                        WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id )
```

OR:

```
UPDATE (SELECT t1.id, 
               t1.name name1,
               t1.desc desc1,
               t2.name name2,
               t2.desc desc2
          FROM table1 t1,
               table2 t2
         WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
   SET name1 = name2,
       desc1 = desc2
```

SOURCE :[enter link description here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php)

Comment: the code is in t-sql and I want the equivalent in pl-sql not t-sql?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but how can I do this with pl-sql collections, specially with nested table?

Comment: this will help: bit.ly/1REHTqA

Comment: this link was also helpful but didn't solve my problem. I have defined RECORD TYPE in package level and 2  table TYPE of those record types.In procedure of that package defined variables of that nested table types.

Comment: @SajjaD: Why do you want to use Pl-SQL collections? Why not global temporary table (GTT)? Performing SET based operation will always be efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "Performing SET based operation will always be efficient." ?